# PyOpenCL, array filter: copy_if vs my own atomic-based implementation

Tags: copy, filtering, opencl, pyopencl, prefix-sum

I have an array of random integers. For example `[132, 2, 31, 49, 15, 6, 70, 18 ... , 99, 1001]`. I want to produce array of all numbers that greater than 100 for example and get size of that array.

There are two ways:

1. New feature of PyOpenCL [`copy_if`](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/algorithm.html#pyopencl.algorithm.copy_if). It's based on
   [`GenericScanKernel`](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/algorithm.html#making-custom-scan-kernels) and if we go deeper on [Prefix Sums](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.128.6230).
2. Pure OpenCL solution that used [Atomics](http://www.cmsoft.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=113&Itemid=168)

Does `copy_if` always works properly? As I can see `copy_if` doesn't use atomic. Is it possible to faced with trouble using `copy_if`?

What about performance of `copy_if` compared to atomic way?

What would you choose and why?

Comment: The two will both work, but in the atomic approach, parallelization will have been quite nullified. The whole point of prefix sums is to keep the GPU pumping at full speed without resorting to slow atomics. In general, having to use atomics indicates you are either using the wrong tool for the job (not a good problem for parallel computing) or the wrong algorithm for the job (probably the case here).

Comment: But may be overhead of parallelization is too big. Do you know some benchmarks that compares that way and atomic way?

Comment: How big is your dataset? For data sets small enough that you would even be able to measure the overhead, you're probably better off doing the calculation in native Python. Also, since you have implementations of both methods, why not benchmark them yourself?

Comment: Dataset is quite big. The reason is that I don't want to implement both of them :) But if I don't find any benchmarks I will make it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen an error with `copy_if`.  Always the same results; it seems very robust.  (I haven't built unit tests, though.)

As for performance, `copy_if` should be much faster, especially if your GPU is fast. As others have said, atomics and GPUs are a bad combination (I have suffered too much to learn this...)

And if the number of expected results is small in relation to your dataset, I have proposed a `sparse_copy_if()` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249558/pyopencl-copy-if-is-it-possible-to-minimize-the-return-buffer-size)---where you can also find a `copy_if` example.

Fork my code and the following should work:

```
from my_pyopencl_algorithm import copy_if 
final_gpu, evt = my_pyopencl_algorithm.sparse_copy_if(array_gpu, "ary[i] > 100", queue = queue)
```